# selecting s:select value using javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp, struts

I have an iterator in jsp and the iterator contains 2 lists:

```
<s:iterator value="reportNamesList">
     <s:select name="hour" listKey="codeDesc" listValue="code" list="hourList" />
     <s:select name="minute" listKey="codeDesc" listValue="code" list="minutesList" />
</s:iterator>
```

Now my requirement is that when hour value is selected (say as 10), the minute dropdown value should also become 10.

I am using javascript. Kindly suggest how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

@Naved is correct; you interact with tag-produced DOM elements the same way as any other (although I'd use jQuery and save yourself a lot of time). You can explicitly set an id by using the `id` element.

In your case, since you'll have multiple groups of select boxes, you'll need to create the id based on something unique in the `reportNamesList`, perhaps an id. Your `id` attribute, then, would probably look something like `id="hours_%{id}` or if you use the `<s:iterator>`'s `var` attribute, `id=hours_%{#foo.id}`.

Your JavaScript would need to bind each hours select to its associated minutes select.

Answer (score 0):

The code seems that you are coding it in Struts2. Although I am not very much aware of it but the simplest way I found to write any javascript for these types of framework is

1. Run your code in browser and view the page source
2. Locate the id or name given to your desired control (in your case it is select for hour). Say it selHour.
3. Write the javascript code using g`etElementById('selHour')` or `getElementsByName('selHour')` and do your stuff.

I hope this will help you to give the proper output.